# Bitbucket ssh public key is being denied but their ssh test connects with no issue

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

A quite probably relevant piece of information is that I have a custom ssh config set up for bitbucket. In my '.ssh/config' file I have the following:

```
[ivanna@comp]$ cat ~/.ssh/config 
Host bitbucket
    Hostname        bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile    /home/ivanna/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The permissions on this file are definitely correct as far as ssh is concerned (I actively use other entries in the config file). Now when I added the remote origin in git I used bitbucket instead of bitbucket.org:

```
git remote add origin bitbucket:ivanna/my-repo.git
```

but when I try to push I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So it seems like I didn't add my public key or something, right? But I definitely did. And when you search for more information you find this page about the error (https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=302811860). And when I do what they say to do to check the key:

```
[ivanna@comp]$ ssh -T hg@bitbucket
logged in as ivanna.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

It can login fine, it seems. So... why doesn't pushing work? The above link mentions that it could be a permissions issue on the project itself but I set the permissions as people suggested and it did nothing. Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ssh -T hg@bitbucket
```

You use `hg@bitbucket` when logging in via SSH, but in the remote URL you add to Git, you don’t specify a username. Since the configuration also does not include one, Git won’t know what username to log in with.

Change the URL to this:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket:ivanna/my-repo.git
```

Alternatively, you can add the user to the SSH config:

```
Host bitbucket
    Hostname        bitbucket.org
    User            git
    IdentityFile    /home/ivanna/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Thank you, that was embarrassing.

Answer (score 4):

If you did this:

```
git remote add origin bitbucket:ivanna/my-repo.git
```

You haven't told `git` that it needs to connect as the something other than your username.  You could do this in your `.ssh/config` file like this:

```
Host bitbucket
    User git
    Hostname        bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile    /home/ivanna/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Or in your `git remote add` command line like this:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket:ivanna/my-repo.git
```

Comment: Well, it's `git@`, he's using git not `hg`.

Comment: If you go and read question (w/ the output from bitbucket) you will see that either should work.  Since the OP is using `hg@` in the question, I stuck with that. I agree it's confusing.  I'll just update the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have tried all the solution still getting permission denied error by bitbucket. Then I simply copied both public key and private key file into the .ssh folder. Finally, it's working.