# Bitbucket: How am I able to push to a repo from a laptop without setting the ssh key for this laptop?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am really confused with the behavior of my bitbucket:

1. I have one project called `Prototype`, under which there are multiple repositories;
2. I am able to push new commits to a repo named `Tiger`; And I assumed that I have had my laptop's ssh key set up in bitbucket's "Personal Settings/SSH Keys", because I would not be able to push commits to `Tiger` if I have not done so.
3. There is another repo named `Cat`, and I just discovered that I am not able to push new commits to it. This really confused me since I am on the same laptop;
4. So I checked my bitbucket's "Personal Settings/SSH Keys", and BOOM! There is no ssh key of my laptop stored in there!

So how am I able to push to `Tiger` in the first place??? I could be mistaken... but I Do remember that I have had my laptop's ssh key stored in bitbucket.

5. I then went ahead and tried to save my laptop's ssh key to bitbucket, but it is saying:
   `Someone has already added that SSH key.`

What the heck is going on?

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're logging in with different accounts. You'll have to either have all repos under the same accounts or create multiple SSH keys

Comment: @fredrik I logged in with an account and I see both repo under the project. Do you mean one of the repos is actually belonging to another account? How is that even possibe? How Am I able to see it then?

Comment: Point 5 means that you're trying to add the same key to two different bitbucket accounts. Without seeing your acutal setup I can't say more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

[Fredrik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72292960/bitbucket-how-am-i-able-to-push-to-a-repo-from-a-laptop-without-setting-the-ssh#comment127719973_72292960) has the key insight (if you'll pardon the phrasing here):

> you're trying to add the same key to two different bitbucket accounts

This is only a problem for ssh authentication, but it's a big problem for ssh authentication.  You must use a *unique* public key per Bitbucket account.

## Long: what's going on

Git itself contains no authentication.  To do its distributed thing, your Git software *must* connect to some other Git software.  The two software versions need not be the same—in fact, some servers may not use (C) Git at all—as long as they both speak the Git *protocol*, but the protocol has no authentication.  It just assumes that by the time the protocol is in use, the server and client already trust each other completely.  So *before* the hosting system believes that you are who you claim to be, you must somehow *prove* that you are.  This is the authentication process.

In general, authentication consists of establishing some sort of *user identity*.  Every web hosting site is a little bit different (for $reasons, sometimes having to do with actual dollars and sometimes `$reasons` just being a metavariable) but there are two general and common ways to authenticate to any of the big Git hosting sites:

- http(s) (mostly https-only these days since plain http is terribly insecure), or
- ssh.

The https authentication has the most variability as there are many https *implementations* and each one has *its own* identity and authorization techniques, so it is the one about which we can say the least.  However, both Bitbucket and GitHub now use *token*-based authentication rather than *password*-based.  The difference between a token and a password is, essentially, that the token is a *structured* password, with the (hidden-from-the-user) structure containing extra information.  One has the web site generate the token (using, usually, a password, and perhaps some second factor for two-factor authentication).  One then directs one's Git to supply a user name and the token-as-the-password.  This pair authenticates you *as* you *to* the hosting site.  The user name here is your identity, and the password-or-token is your proof of identity (so guard it carefully!).

To use this method with Git, use a URL that begins with `https://`.  These take the form `https://user@host/path/passed/to/host` (although you *can* shove the password / token in here, or leave out the `user` part, it's usually simplest to include the user and leave out the password, so that only the password has to be managed via some credential system).

The ssh authentication is much more uniform, perhaps because there are fewer ssh implementations and most trace their history back to a common starting point.  To use ssh authentication with Git, use a URL that begins with `ssh://` or that has the form `user@host:path`, e.g., `git@bitbucket.org:my/repo.git`.  The ssh system uses *[public-key cryptography;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)* there is no password involved here, at least at this point.

Your Git software does not do any of the authentication on its own, but it *can* use a *credential helper*.  It does so only for https authentication.  This is highly configurable, and has a lot of system dependencies.  It's also not what the original question is about, so that's all we'll say about it here.

#### Using ssh authentication with Git and big hosting sites

When you use ssh to authenticate, there's a user name involved, and it's right there in the URL: `ssh://user@host/path` or `user@host:path`.  The `ssh://` part (if using this form) and the at-sign `@ and colon (if using this form) are literal characters that will appear in the URL.

All the big Git servers *require* that you supply the *`user`* part as the literal string `git`.  That is, they are going to authenticate you not as *yourself* but rather as the `git` pseudo-user.  There are a bunch of technical reasons for this, but they all boil down to "it was easier that way, and now it's the convention".  Since you're going to claim to be this `git` pseudo-user, *not* whoever you *really* are, the host is going to need to figure out who you *really* are in some other way.  The way the big Git servers do this is by cheating.

If we look at public-key cryptography, we see that it works by having you (or your Git software, or in this particular case, the ssh program—Git literally *runs* `ssh` here as Git does not contain the ssh code itself) provide *to* the server a public key: a long, random-looking string of letters and digits and perhaps other characters that represent some kind of cryptographic key.  The *public* key is called this because it's *not* a secret!  You may show it to literally anyone, although there's no good reason to [bruit it about](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bruit).

Along with this public key, whatever it is, there's a paired *private* key, which you should keep secret (guard it carefully, like a password).  Given the *public* key only, anyone can easily encrypt any data; the holder of the *private* key can use the private key to easily *decrypt* that same data, but one who lacks the private key cannot.<sup>1</sup>  So when using ssh, you connect to the server—Bitbucket, in this case—and claim to be user `git` and send them a public key.  They use the public key to encrypt a randomly-chosen string, you use your *private* key to *decrypt* it and send that back, and they see that you are in fact in possession of the private key.

But: how will they know *who you are?*  You claimed to be the `git` pseudo-user.  This is where the cheating comes in: every public/private key-pair has a *unique* public key.<sup>2</sup>  So, at some point—long before you use ssh to connect *to* the hosting server—you must connect to the hosting server with `https` (and a user name and password, and perhaps 2FA) and *upload to the hosting server* the *public key* you plan to use later with your ssh connection.

At this point, the hosting server—Bitbucket, in this case—look in a big table or database that they have for *all public keys*.  If the public key you just gave them is *already in the table*, they give you the error you saw:

> `Someone has already added that SSH key.`

That *someone* could be you.  In fact, assuming uniqueness of public keys, it *must* be you!  They don't tell you who, they just tell you *you cannot add this one now, because I, bitbucket, already have it*.  (Should you wish to find out who they think this particular public key represents, you simply have to run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.com`: you have the private key too, and your ssh will use it to decrypt what they send, and you'll successfully log in, and they will tell you who they think you are.)

Assuming the key is *not* in their big table / database, they add it, *along with the user name you've used to log in to their site using https*.  And now the hosting server knows that if someone—anyone!—comes along in the future and offers *that* public key, that "someone" is claiming to be *you*.  If that someone can also decrypt the random string they offer as a challenge, that someone has the private key too, and therefore *is* you.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not, that is, without something deeply magical like a sufficiently powerful quantum computer.  ["Post-quantum" cryptography](https://www.infoq.com/articles/post-quantum-cryptography-introduction/), as discussed in the linked article, is an attempt to defend against this future threat.

<sup>2</sup>This is not guaranteed in any technical sense, but enough extra data and other junk is included *in* the public key that in any *practical* sense, it will always be unique.  Git itself has the same problem with object hash IDs: they're only unique *in practice*, not in theory.  [In theory, theory and practice are the same, but in practice they're not. —Benjamin Brewster, most likely](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2018/04/14/theory/)

---

#### What happened in your case

It's impossible to be certain.  Perhaps you're using https authentication for one repository, and ssh authentication for another.

You do, however, now know that you can run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` to see *who they think you are*.  This is based on the *public* key you offer them.  If you need to have multiple accounts *on* Bitbucket, you'll need to carefully control *which* public keys you offer.

Note that ssh can use an *agent* to store key-pairs: this allows you to avoid storing the key-pairs directly on the computer you're using (e.g., if you're going through an intermediate work machine that's shared, you might want to keep your laptop-side keys on the non-shared laptop and use the agent to pass them through to the shared machine only briefly as needed).  However, when you *do* use an agent, you lose some control over which keys are offered at which point in ssh negotiations.  The `.ssh/config` file lets you specify that only some *particular* key should be given out.  You can also use this mechanism to say that your ssh should supply the pseudo-user `git` user name: see, e.g., [Bitbucket ssh public key is being denied but their ssh test connects with no issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31660263/1256452) (a question that dates back to the era when Bitbucket was still a Mercurial server, during the transition).