# What is the correct way to add SSH keys for multiple accounts on a single machine?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm using `bitbucket.org` to my manage my repositories both at work and personally.

On my new MacBook Pro, I generated a new SSH key and then added that to my work account on bitbucket.org and have had no issues with committing my work. This key is saved on my machine at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Now, I am trying to add my personal account on the machine, and having all types of issues with committing my work.

I generated a `ssh` key using the following command:

`ssh-keygen`

I saved this key at `~/.ssh/id_personal_rsa` and then copy the key into my personal bitbucket.org account.

I then created a `config` file at `~/.ssh/config` that has the follow entries:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host bitbucket.org-personal
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_personal_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

(The `personal` string is just replaced with my actual account name.)

Now, for the issue, when I try and commit work, I am getting this error:

```
Git: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is the `config` file for my .ssh connection in my project:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org-personal:personal/my-personal-project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Any thoughts on what I may have configured incorrectly?

**UPDATE:**
I've updated my config for my personal account to reflect some of the answers from this post and from this link: [Bitbucket ssh public key is being denied but their ssh test connects with no issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660263/bitbucket-ssh-public-key-is-being-denied-but-their-ssh-test-connects-with-no-iss).

When I run this command: `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org-personal`, I get this response:

```
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

However, I am still getting `Permission denied` when trying to commit my new changes.

Comment: `git remote set-orl origin personal@bitbucket.org-personal:personal/my-personal-project.git` The key part is the host name `bitbucket.org-personal` — it must be the name from `.ssh/config`.

Comment: Thanks for the look @phd. I tried to change the `Host` for my personal account back to just `bitbucket.org` because that was the actual URL of remote origin, but I am getting the same error. `Git: personal@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: 1. It's exactly the other way around — host in remote URL must be from SSH, not Host in SSH should be from Git; test with `ssh -Tv personal@bitbucket.org-personal`. 2. The order of Hosts in `.ssh/config` should be from the most specific to generic; i.e. first `Host bitbucket.org-personal`, last `Host *`

Comment: Oh - so the URL of the remote origin doesn't need to be an actual URL that resolves to anything? I will give that a try and report back. Thanks @phd!

Comment: @phd - I changed the config around and I am still unable to push any commits. I am getting the same error. Is there something different I need to generate the ssh key for that account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `User` entry should be set to `git`, not "`personal`".
You never establish an SSH connection to a Git repositories remote hosting server with a user account, always with a technical service account (generally named `git`).
The authentication is done through the SSH key used.

Second, once you have set an Host entry named `bitbucket.org-personal`, you can check if it works with:

```
ssh -Tv bitbucket.org-personal
```

Finally, the remote URL to use would be:

```
bitbucket.org-personal:personal/my-personal-project.git
```

---

Note that, as noted in this [BitBucket thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/could-not-read-from-remote-repository/qaq-p/983015#M49245), you need to register the key on the account level, not the repository level.

[image: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/72754i5481CF5C1AC9558A/image-dimensions/2500?v=v2&px=-1]

> 1. Remove the SSH key from the repo.
>    (Click on `repo name > Settings > Access Keys`)
> 2. Add SSH key to Account settings SSH keys.
>    (Click on your `avatar > Bitbucket Settings > SSH Keys`)

As mentioned in "[Can't git push to Bitbucket: Unauthorized - fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56828686/6309)"

> adding the keys under the repo only gives you a read-only access.
> For read and write access, you need to add your keys under your account.

Comment: I've updated my original post to reflect some of these changes. When I check the SSH connection for that entry I am told I am authenticated with that key, however, I am still unable to commit any changes to the repo. I still get this error: `Git: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: @zeropsi What does `git remote -v` return, when executed in your repository folder?

Comment: ```origin  git@bitbucket.org-personal:personal/my-personal-project.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org-personal:personal/my-personal-project.git (push)```

Comment: @zeropsi nno need for the `git@` part: it is included in your `~/.ssh/config` file, the  `User git` line. Beside that, do you get the error when pushing (`git push`)? Can you, for testing, *clone* in a separate empty local folder the repository, using the `bitbucket.org-personal:personal/my-personal-project.git` URL?

Comment: yes, I was able to clone the repo using that URL.

Comment: And when I attempt a `git push` from the original working directory, this is the error I get: ```Enter passphrase for key '/Users/zeropsi/.ssh/id_personal_rsa': 
Unauthorized
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.```

Comment: @zeropsi But can you push from the new cloned repository though?

Comment: No, I was not able to push from the cloned repo. Same error message. However, it asked me to a configure a username and email for the repo, so I edited the `config` file in my projects `.git` folder to add: ```[user]
 name = personal
 email = personal@gmail.com```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247311/discussion-between-vonc-and-zeropsi).