# Cloning remote repository gives fatal Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys, openssh

Hi I think I need some help.
I'm using Bitbucket. I have Git and Git-bash as well as Cygwin installed in Windows 10.
I'm trying to clone from cmd window.

I want to be able to run git commands from Git-bash, cygwin and from cmd window...is that doable?
Anyway nothing is working now, so I started with Windows cmd.

My SSH config file is located here: c:\Users<my user id>.ssh\config

```
Host <info removed>
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms  +ssh-rsa
```

I also have two SSH files with in my SSH folder:

- id_rsa
- id_rsa.pub
  I have followed this guide: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Which has been generated with the command:

```
C:\Users\<info removed>\.ssh>ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
...
no passkey added
...
```

Uploaded the public key within id.rsa.pub to Bitbucket and put it with SSH keys.

I have an sshd_config here:
C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config
No changes made but I think some interesting lines are:

```
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? name -like "openssh*"
...gives installed for both server and client

Run some additional commands:

Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic

Start-Service ssh-agent

ssh-add $HOME\.ssh\id_rsa

```
C:\Users\<my user id>\source\repos>git clone ssh://<info removed>.git  --config core.sshCommand="ssh -v"
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to <info removed> port <info removed>.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/<my user id>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version APACHE-SSHD-2.2.0
debug1: compat_banner: no match: APACHE-SSHD-2.2.0
debug1: Authenticating to <info removed> as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match)
Unable to negotiate with <info removed> port <info removed>: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also don't understand when, where and why all config files are used.

Sound like the id_rsa.pub has not been added to Bitbucket but it has!

This line "Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config" is confusing when I'm using Windows.

So please, I really need some help to get this working.

Comment: debug1: kex: algorithm: **ecdh-sha2-nistp256**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this a problem? I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: It's not just *a* problem, it is *the* problem-so-far. They (whoever they are) only allow `ecdh-sha2-nistp256`. Your ssh client doesn't *know* `ecdh-sha2-nistp256`. You cannot get there from here: your client speaks only Arabic, their server understands only Chinese. One or both of these two systems must be upgraded or downgraded or sidegraded or something, so that they both speak the same language.

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/no-matching-host-key-found/qaq-p/1007297) and "[SSH-RSA key rejected with message "no mutual signature algorithm"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html)"

> In order to re-enable ssh-rsa support, inserting the following line into the affected SSH client's config file can re-enable this algorithm (`%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`):
>
> PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa

Alternatively, you can generate a [ed25519 public key algorithm](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen#choosing-an-algorithm-and-key-size)

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -P ""
```

---

The [OP fishfloat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17080645/fishfloat) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371491/cloning-remote-repository-gives-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository/73383137#comment129638082_73383137) having reinstalled Git For Windows, selecting to use external SSH client and that solved it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I tested to change to "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa" and that did not help then I generate with your command above the files id_ed25519 and id_ed25519.pub, then I uploaded the public  key to bitbucket. This did not help either.
Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: @Fishfloat Did you uploaded the key to the [right setting page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73368969/6309)? If so, what is the new error message?

Comment: Weird, I actually reinstalled Git but selected to use external SSH client and that solved it.

Comment: @Fishfloat Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.